# How to go from last row to first row direstly in uitableview?

Tags: iphone

iam making one application.In that iam using UITableview.In that i places one button at the last row of the tableview.How we go to first row when we click on that button.So please tell me how to solve this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSIndexPath *topIndexPath;
topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```